# Jersey json POST without DTO

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, spring-boot-starter

The below code works

```
@POST
@Path("/{apiId}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response postMetricsData(String metricsData) {
    System.out.println(metricsData);
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

The below code is throwing error

```
@POST
@Path("/{apiId}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response postMetricsData(String metricsData, @PathParam("apiId") String apiId) {
    System.out.println(metricsData);
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

Getting below exception

```
rg.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
```

[[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.trimble.paas.apicloud.metricscollector.resource.MetricsResource.postMetricsData(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) at index 1.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=POST, consumedTypes=[application/json], producedTypes=[], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=class com.trimble.paas.apicloud.metricscollector.resource.MetricsResource, handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@59916e0f]}, definitionMethod=public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.trimble.paas.apicloud.metricscollector.resource.MetricsResource.postMetricsData(java.lang.String,java.lang.String), parameters=[Parameter [type=class java.lang.String, source=null, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class java.lang.String, source=apiId, defaultValue=null]], responseType=class javax.ws.rs.core.Response}, nameBindings=[]}']
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:394)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$1(ApplicationHandler.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.(ApplicationHandler.java:282)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.(WebComponent.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:178)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:370)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:789)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Any idea on what I am missing?

Comment: What's the `@PathParam` import package? It should be `javax.ws.rs`. If you're using `javax.websocket.server` (which I've seen some people mistakenly do), you will get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Would you check the import of the @PathParam. Try to use the import javax.ws.rd;